# Is using "function.variable = something" a global variable

Tags: python, global-variables, global

For example, if I have a function like:

```
def function():
    function.number = 1

def calling():
    print(function.number)
```

Is function.number considered a global variable? Is calling variables like this unadvisable?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function.number` is an *expression* that evaluates to the value of some object's `number` attribute. `function` itself is a global (or at least non-local) variable which is presumed to reference an object that has a `number` attribute.

---

Strictly speaking, `function` is a *free* variable; which scope the name resolves in depends on the context in which `function` is defined. Consider, for example,

```
def foo():
    def function():
        function.number = 1
    
    def calling():
        print(function.number)

    function()
    calling()
```

Here, `function` is a *local* variable, defined in the scope of `foo`, but it used non-locally inside the definitions of `function` and `calling`.

Comment: I understand, so it's fine to keep using the expressions?

Comment: It's *legal*; it's a design issue whether you should using function attributes or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will be consider as a attribute of function. You can check on ipython:

```
In [1]: def function():
   ...:     function.number = 1
   ...:
   ...: def calling():
   ...:     print(function.number)
   ...:

In [3]: function()

In [4]: calling()
1

In [5]: dir()
Out[5]:
['In',
 'Out',
 '_',
 '__',
 '___',
 '__builtin__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 '_dh',
 '_i',
 '_i1',
 '_i2',
 '_i3',
 '_i4',
 '_i5',
 '_ih',
 '_ii',
 '_iii',
 '_oh',
 'calling',
 'exit',
 'function',
 'get_ipython',
 'quit']

In [6]: type(function)
Out[6]: function

In [7]: type(function.number)
Out[7]: int

In [8]: dir(function)
Out[8]:
['__annotations__',
 '__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__closure__',
 '__code__',
 '__defaults__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__get__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__globals__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__kwdefaults__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__name__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__qualname__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'number']
```

Answer (score 0):

No.
If you want to have a global variable, you declare it in the global scope. Means:

```
number = 1

def function():
    something

def calling():
    some other thing
```

Now if you don't have a variable named `number` in the function you can access (Read) the value from the variable.

If you want to modify the variable from a function you'll need to use the keyword `global` as such:

```
number = 1

def function():
    global number
    number = 3

def calling():
    print(number)
```

Comment: Note that `number = 1` doesn't *have* to be present in the global scope. If `number` doesn't exist yet when `function` is called for the first time, it will still be created in the global scope owing to the use of `global number`.